# How to install packages of 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

For some reason, I have to install some packages of Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.10. I've tried to `apt update && apt install pkgname` but there are always some dependency issues.

What I'm trying is that I get the source of some package with the command `apt source pkgname`.

I've found that I got three things:

```
pkgname.dsc
pkgname.orig.tar.gz
pkgname.debian.tar.xz
```

The `.dsc` file seems to contain some information of `pkgname`, the `.orig.tar.gz` file is the source code, but I don't know what the `.debian.tar.xz` file is.

For example, to install `libpcl-dev`, I did things as below:

`apt source libpcl-dev && tar xzvf pcl.orig.tar.gz && cd pcl && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make install && make`.

It seems to work but I can't get what I need, which means that there isn't a file named `libpcl-dev` in `/usr`.

Comment: @fkraiem   For some reason, I can't use `apt install` to install a package.

Comment: @fkraiem  well, in fact I have to try to install some packages of 16.04 to 17.10... Maybe I should tell my boss that it's not possible..

Comment: You should really edit your question to describe your actual problem. Apparently you want to install the `libpcl-dev` package from 16.04 on 17.10? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @fkraiem  check my re-edition.

Comment: You say "some packages"; which ones? Only PCL packages or also others? PCL is okay, but others might not be.

Comment: @fkraiem For now I don't know all of packages that I have to install. So for PCL, what should I do? Install it from source?

Comment: »» to install libpcl-dev, I did things as .. «« : `cmake .. && make && sudo make install` : This will install everything. But doesn't make a package.deb (libpcl-dev). And makes no entries to the package base : The install will be unknown by `apt` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the binary (`.deb`) package of `libpcl-dev` from the 16.04 repositories on a 17.10 system is difficult, if not impossible, due to its many dependencies, some of which have to be installed from 16.04 and may conflict with packages already installed from 17.10.

However, building the source package from 16.04 on a 17.10 system is possible, because all the build dependencies are available in 17.10.

First make a directory to work in

```
mkdir ~/libpcl
cd ~/libpcl
```

Get the source package

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pcl/pcl_1.7.2.orig.tar.gz
tar xf pcl_1.7.2.orig.tar.gz
cd pcl-pcl-1.7.2
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pcl/pcl_1.7.2-14build1.debian.tar.xz -O - | tar xJ
debuild
```

Probably when you run `debuild` you will get a "command not found" telling you to install `devscripts`; install it and run `debuild` again. Now it will complain that some build dependencies are missing; install them and run `debuild` again, and now the build should be successful (errors about `debsign` can be ignored). You will have some `.deb`s in your `~/libpcl` directory, which you can install as usual.

**Warning:** if some bugs, including security issues, are found in this version of PCL and a fixed version is released in 16.04, you **will not** automatically get it; instead you must repeat the above process with the new source package.